# How to to search a key in an xml and replace it's value with Python?

Tags: python, xml, string

I have thousands of these app name lines in an xml file:

```
<app name="app-sq-461-author-core-0">
```

I want to do the following:

1. check through all lines that 'app name' exists
2. if so, see if the value matches "test"
3. If so, replace the value with "delete me"

Currently, I have:

```
bare = importedxml.find('app name')
testvalue = bare.split("=")[1]
if testvalue = "test" in importedxml:
   testvalue = "delete me"
```

What is the best way to do this?  I'm encountering many problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have You tried [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)? 
Something along these lines

```
import bs4

xml = "Your bare XML String"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml)
test_apps = soup.findChildren("app", {"name": "test"})
for app in test_apps:
    app["name"] = "delete me"

with open("filename.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

but, as you mentioned in you comment below, that you do not have bs4, the only thing I can think of is using a regex replace.

```
import re

xml = "your XML String"
pattern = re.compile('app name="test"')
replaced = pattern.sub('app name="delete me"', xml)
```

Comment: Yea I really want to switch over to beautiful soup, the problem is getting my work place to approve.  So for now, I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/<app name="foo">/<app name="bar">/g' < file.xml > file.xml.new
mv file.xml file.xml.old
mv file.xml.new file.xml
```

Comment: How do you know, that op has a *nix machine?

Comment: I don't.  The command syntax ought to be similar enough, no?  And even if op's machine does not have sed at all, the intent of the operation is clear.